# Is it guaranteed that std::chrono::steady_clock never wraps around?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Basically:

```
auto p1 = std::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

... // do smth for unspecified period of time

auto p2 = std::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();

assert(p2 >= p1);   // is this guaranteed?
```

?

If yes -- how it this guaranteed? By making sure no C++ program ever runs for longer than `std::steady_clock::duration::max() - std::steady_clock::duration::zero()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like many things in this topical area, it's complicated...

Yes, it is guaranteed that `steady_clock::now()` never wraps, as it is guaranteed that it always increases:

http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.steady

> Objects of class `steady_­clock` represent clocks for which values of
> `time_­point` never decrease as physical time advances and for which
> values of `time_­point` advance at a steady rate relative to real
> time. That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

But...

> how is this guaranteed?!

Technically it is not possible to have a clock with finite memory tick forever and never run out of range.  So technically, the answer is no.

But ...

As a practical manner, all implementations of `steady_clock` count `nanoseconds` using signed 64 bit integral types.  The range on this is +/-292 years.  And it is common for the epoch to be the last time your computer booted up.  So practically, it won't wrap in your lifetime.  Thus when it wraps, it will be somebody else's problem, and the computer involved will get some kind of award for having an uptime of that length of time.

PS:  I can't wait for the computer manuals to come out that say:

> Must be rebooted at least once every 292 years.

:-)

Comment: 640K ought to be enough for anybody. Or what was the canonical quote for such?

Comment: Classic!  But quickly edit to 640Kb for historical accuracy... :-)

Comment: I guess it is safe to assume that `GetTickCount()` (or similar) is never used to implement `steady_clock` or OS will kill my app from time to time.

Comment: `GetTickCount()` would be a conforming implementation.  But would be disappointingly coarse with millisecond resolution.  Visual Studio `steady_clock::duration` is `nanoseconds`.

Comment: Done. Though it is apocryphal afaik

Comment: @HowardHinnant ... just making sure that if given compiler decided to use `GetTickCount()` -- "no-wraparound" is still guaranteed by C++ standard. :)

Comment: Reference:  Visual Studio `steady_clock::now()` implementation: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/chrono#L604-L615

Comment: Yes, the standard says:  "values of time_­point never decrease as physical time advances".  If the vendor violates that, then the standards police force is immediately notified.

Comment: LOL... To give you some context -- I am replacing some old `GetTickCount()`- based code with `steady_clock`-based. This guarantee allows me to throw away all magic old code had wrt wraparounds...

Comment: Cool!  Fwiw, you can also write a custom clock that implements `now()` with a call to `GetTickCount()`, and returns a `milliseconds`-precision `time_point`.  Doing so might offer you a more gentle 2-phase transition to the chrono system.  First go to the custom clock, without changing precision.  And then go to steady_clock with the change in precision.

Comment: Neat idea, though probably an overkill in this instance.